# Pivot: Create column to capture duplicate cycle dates

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I have the below tables. The join from cycle to program is date based. 
There are millions of PGMID entries, so I was thinking about pivoting feature but I can't hard code the PGMID. Any thoughts/help would be appreciated. 
I do have the ability to edit tables in the db.

Table: Cycle

```
 ID     START_CYCLE END_CYCLE
 4400   7/22/2018   8/3/2018
 4400   8/4/2018    8/5/2018
 4400   8/6/2018    8/6/2018
 4400   8/7/2018    8/9/2018
 4400   8/10/2018   9/6/2018
 4400   9/7/2018    9/7/2018
 4400   9/8/2018    9/9/2018
 4400   9/10/2018   12/31/9999
```

Table: Program

```
PGMID  START_DT    END_DT
 101    8/4/2018   9/10/2018
 102    9/8/2018   9/8/2018
 103    9/10/2018  NULL
```

Output:

```
 ID   START_CYCLE   END_CYCLE  PGMID       
 4400  7/22/2018    8/3/2018     
 4400   8/4/2018    8/5/2018    101
 4400   8/6/2018    8/6/2018    101
 4400   8/7/2018    8/9/2018    101
 4400   8/10/2018   9/6/2018    101
 4400   9/7/2018    9/7/2018    101
 4400   9/8/2018    9/9/2018    101
 4400   9/8/2018    9/9/2018    102
 4400   9/10/2018   12/31/9999  103
```

There are duplicate cycle entries, I do NOT want any repeat dates.

```
 4400   9/8/2018    9/9/2018    101
 4400   9/8/2018    9/9/2018    102
```

Expected output:

```
 ID   START_CYCLE   END_CYCLE  PROGRAM1  PROGRAM2       
 4400  7/22/2018    8/3/2018     
 4400   8/4/2018    8/5/2018    101
 4400   8/6/2018    8/6/2018    101
 4400   8/7/2018    8/9/2018    101
 4400   8/10/2018   9/6/2018    101
 4400   9/7/2018    9/7/2018    101
 4400   9/8/2018    9/9/2018    101      102
 4400   9/10/2018   12/31/9999  103
```

Comment: Well, what have you tried as SQL so far ?

Comment: Do you really need a separate column for each PROGRAM, or would it be OK to have one column with a list of PROGRAMs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select * 
  from (
    select id, start_cycle, end_cycle, pgmid, case when rn > 5 then 0 else rn end rn
      from (
        select id, start_cycle, end_cycle, pgmid, 
               row_number() over (partition by id, start_cycle, end_cycle order by pgmid) rn
          from cycle c
          left join program p on p.start_dt <= c.end_cycle and c.start_cycle <= p.end_dt ))
  pivot (listagg(pgmid, ',') within group (order by pgmid) 
         for rn in (1 program1, 2 program2, 3 program3, 4 program4, 5 program5, 0 others))
  order by id, start_cycle
```

- left join data as you did,
- add row_number() partitioned by each cycle and ordered by `pgmid`,
- if this number exceeds some number (in my case it is 5) then assign `0` instead,
- make pivot using this column. First five columns are built as always, last which may contain more program is called `others`
- instead of typically used in pivot `min` or `max` use `listagg`

These steps were needed to show all programs if there are more than 5 of them per cycle. All the rest are in `others`. If you know that there can be no more than, let's say 3 programs, then you can simplify this query.

If you want each program in different column and number of maximum columns is unknown then it's dynamic pivot problem. There are some solutions already described on Stack Overflow, but these are mostly workarounds.

Here is an example where we have up to 8 programs in one cycle:

```
with 
  cycle(id, start_cycle, end_cycle) as (
    select 4400, date '2018-07-22', date '2018-08-03' from dual union all
    select 4400, date '2018-08-04', date '2018-08-05' from dual union all
    select 4400, date '2018-08-06', date '2018-08-06' from dual union all
    select 4400, date '2018-08-07', date '2018-08-09' from dual union all
    select 4400, date '2018-08-10', date '2018-09-06' from dual union all
    select 4400, date '2018-09-07', date '2018-09-07' from dual union all
    select 4400, date '2018-09-08', date '2018-09-09' from dual union all
    select 4400, date '2018-09-10', date '9999-12-31' from dual ), 
  program(pgmid, start_dt, end_dt) as (
    select 101, date '2018-08-04', date '2018-09-10' from dual union all
    select 104, date '2018-08-06', date '2018-08-07' from dual union all
    select 105, date '2018-08-06', date '2018-08-07' from dual union all
    select 106, date '2018-08-06', date '2018-08-07' from dual union all
    select 107, date '2018-08-06', date '2018-08-07' from dual union all
    select 108, date '2018-08-06', date '2018-08-07' from dual union all
    select 109, date '2018-08-06', date '2018-08-07' from dual union all
    select 110, date '2018-08-07', date '2018-08-07' from dual union all
    select 102, date '2018-09-08', date '2018-09-08' from dual union all
    select 103, date '2018-09-10', null  from dual )
select * 
  from (
    select id, start_cycle, end_cycle, pgmid, case when rn > 5 then 0 else rn end rn
      from (
        select id, start_cycle, end_cycle, pgmid, 
               row_number() over (partition by id, start_cycle, end_cycle order by pgmid) rn
          from cycle c
          left join program p on p.start_dt <= c.end_cycle and c.start_cycle <= p.end_dt ))
  pivot (listagg(pgmid, ',') within group (order by pgmid) 
         for rn in (1 program1, 2 program2, 3 program3, 4 program4, 5 program5, 0 others))
  order by id, start_cycle
```

Result:

```
    ID START_CYCLE END_CYCLE   PROGRAM1  PROGRAM2  PROGRAM3  PROGRAM4  PROGRAM5  OTHERS
 ----- ----------- ----------- --------- --------- --------- --------- --------- ------------
  4400 2018-07-22  2018-08-03                                                    
  4400 2018-08-04  2018-08-05  101                                               
  4400 2018-08-06  2018-08-06  101       104       105       106       107       108,109
  4400 2018-08-07  2018-08-09  101       104       105       106       107       108,109,110
  4400 2018-08-10  2018-09-06  101                                               
  4400 2018-09-07  2018-09-07  101                                               
  4400 2018-09-08  2018-09-09  101       102                                     
  4400 2018-09-10  9999-12-31  101
```

**<sup>[dbfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=f944321d9429cd9fb020d05b4445488b)</sup>**

Answer (score 0):

1- You must be add "group by START_CYCLE, END_CYCLE"
2- In select section must be add group_concat(PGMID separator ',')

I don't knowledge of oracle for above but in mysql is :

```
select ..., group_concat(PGMID separator ',') as PGMIDs, ... 
from ... 
join ... 
where ... 
group by START_CYCLE, END_CYCLE
```

I hope to help you.